# How to resize an image without stretching?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a bitmap of 128*128 size. I want to make it of size 256*256. But I don't want to stretch the image. Instead, my old image should be placed at the center of the new image and remaining pixels should be filled with a certain color, for example white.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

ImageView have setScaleType(ScaleType type) method.

When ScaleType is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Try to play with it. Good luck!!